# Write in 5-5-5 RGB and read in RGBA, BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, rgb, bufferedimage

What I want to do can be explained shortly. Let's consider a number "x". I operate on an image with TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB. I use setRGB(x), save the image. Unfortunately Java obligates me to read the resulting image with TYPE_INT_ARGB through getRGB. How can I find my initial x?
What worries me the most is that while some numbers read through getRGB are equal between them, this pattern of equivalence is not respected in the source, here's what I mean:

READ:
-16777216
-16777216
-16777216
-16777183
-16777117
-16777101
-16777093
-16777101

SOURCE: 
00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70   (in HEX)

The numbers in position 6 and 8 are equal in the read file, but different in the source (74 != 70)

```
//Write part:
BufferedImage img=new BufferedImage(8, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);
      for(int q=0;q<8;q++)
          img.setRGB(q,0,realVal[q]);//realVal contains the hex values
  File f= new File("randomfile.bmp");
  ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", f);

//Read part:
BufferedImage img;
        try{
        img=ImageIO.read(new File("randomfile.bmp"));
        for(int q=0;q<8;q++)
            System.out.println(img.getRGB(q,0));
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: your hex values are probably Red Green Blue; put down some code and will see what you are doing

Comment: the 555_RGB is a very complicated model and it will almost certainly distort the values - you need to get the equations if you really need that - why do you need 555? cant you use regular RGB? what kind of processing you expect to do with this image - you might as well use arrays

Comment: Just realized that the hex values from your source spells " ftyp". Are you sure that is your pixel values? Or are you looking at a *file* in a hex editor, expecting the bytes of the file to equal the pixel values in your image???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB` type uses a packed 15 bit (or 16 bit, but the 16th bit is not used) representation for pixels, where each R, G and B sample uses 5 bits.

The `BufferedImage.getRGB(...)` methods on the other hand, are *convenience methods* for getting/setting the color of a single or a group of pixels, and always operates on a packed 32 bit ARGB representation, where each A, R, G and B sample uses 8 bits (and the color model is always sRGB), just like `TYPE_INT_ARGB` as you say. Because of this difference in representation, the 5 bit samples needs to be "scaled" to 8 bits (and back) for retrieval/storage, which is slow and may create rounding/truncating errors.

However, you don't need to use this representation if you don't like to. Instead, you can access the "`ushort`" (Java does not have unsigned integral types, so they are stored as `short`s) directly through the `Raster`/`DataBuffer`:

```
DataBufferUShort dataBuffer = (DataBufferUShort) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
short[] data = dataBuffer.getData(); // Get the backing array
```

Any changes to the backing array will be reflected in the image (it's a "live" view). Also, accessing the backing array will most likely disable any chances of hardware acceleration, but that may not be an issue (it's not in the code you posted, as it only reads/writes the image, no display).

---

That said, you should consider @gpasch's comment, and see if you could just use the `TYPE_INT_RGB` or `TYPE_INT_ARGB` models, as they are usually easier to work with (especially if you don't like bit twiddling).

And a final warning: Not all file formats will support the `TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB` pixel layout. BMP does though.

Comment: The other models I can use are TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED and TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, I'll try those.

Comment: @Christian The point isn't to avoid using `TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB`, but rather that `TYPE_INT_RGB` and `TYPE_INT_ARGB` are the only ones where you can rely on `getRGB(...)` methods return the same values as set by `setRGB(...)`. Using `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` or `TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` will not help in this regard. It might help our understand of the problem, if you state *why* you would need to use these "special" types?

Comment: The reason is simply that I want to understand why the JavaDoc says that TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED and TYPE_BYTE_GRAY are 1 byte encoded but when I try to do a putRGB(q,0,q) with q from 0 to 255, and I open the image with paint and read the rgb, I notice a lot of pixels are rounded so that from 0 to 20(e.g.) (as int rgb) I get the same pixel. That means those encoding don't use 1 byte, but Java says so, I'm perplexed.

Comment: @Christian The *in-memory* **storage** of those types are 1 byte (as the JavaDoc says). The *encoding* depends on the file format. The `setRGB(...)/getRGB(...)` methods use a 32 bit packed *representation*, but this is not what is actually stored anywhere, these values are converted for you, because it's a convenient format to work with.

Comment: Also, from the `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` JavaDoc: *[w]hen color data is stored in an image of this type, the closest color in the colormap is determined by the `IndexColorModel` and the resulting index is stored. **Approximation and loss of alpha or color components can result** [...]* (emphasis mine). So, this is as expected.